# Removing index.php and handling subdomains of two Codeigniter sites, when one within the other

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two Codeigniter sites, one sitting within the subdirectory of the other. I need some help modifying my htaccess file to remove index.php from both.

The first site, `http://subdomain.domain.com` is stored in `/home/sites/subdomain/www/html/`

The second, `http://test.subdomain.domain.com` lives in `/home/sites/subdomain/www/html/app_staging/`

This is my .htacess file from `/home/sites/subdomain/www/html/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite the main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !test.subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Rewrite the sub domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test.subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /app_staging/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This is removing index.php from the from the first site, everything is ok there. On the second site, I can load the default controller form `http://test.subdomain.domain.com`, but subsequent pages return a 404 from the server. What are my next steps?

Comment: Could you give the given answer a try? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Haven't forgotten about your answer @HashemQolami, just investigating a potential underlying issue with htaccess on our server. I will let you know how your answer goes once that's resolved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put each of two `.htaccess` files inside their own root CI folder.

Personally, I prefer restricting requested files and/or folders in order to prevent them from being treated by `RewriteRule`.

So, for the first file which is located at `/home/sites/subdomain/www/html/`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And for the other one is located at `/home/sites/subdomain/www/html/app_staging/`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_staging/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** You must add `css` and other folders *(like `public`)* to `RewriteCond` if you don’t want them to be treated by `RewriteRule`.

***As a side-note:** You might want to prevent directory listing by using the following inside each `.htaccess` file:*

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```